# how to select unique id and not used before

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to write select statement. Sorry for my bad english I couldnt explain it exactly in question title.

you can also see my question here [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a792a/3)

I have values like;

```
values (22222222222, "john", 0);
values (11111111111, "nic", 1);
values (22222222222, "john", 0);
values (22222222222, "john", 1);
values (44444444444, "tom", 0);
values (33333333333, "hans", 0);
values (11111111111, "nic", 1);
values (33333333333, "hans", 0);
values (33333333333, "hans", 0);
```

I want to select where result=0, but if one of the id's result=1 I also dont want it.

After select I expect result;

```
values (44444444444, "tom", 0);
values (33333333333, "hans", 0);
```

and total count of distinct id.

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding the criteria. Why are those two rows selected if their `result` is `0`?

Comment: sorry, you are right.. it is my mistake I edit my question

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `NOT EXISTS` ([SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a792a/4)):

```
select *
from myTable t
where result = 0
and not exists (
    select 1
    from myTable t2
    where t2.id = t.id
    and t2.result = 1
)
```

Which reads exactly as it looks. Select rows with `result = 0` where there is not a row for the same `id` with `result = 1`.

To group and count it's as simple as adding the aggregate and group-by ([SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a792a/15)):

```
select id, count(*)
from myTable t
where result = 0
and not exists (
    select 1
    from myTable t2
    where t2.id = t.id
    and t2.result = 1
)
group by id
```

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise :)

Comment: I am actually, c++ programmer and I need to give numbers for statistic to my boss :) so please I have lots of work to do, I can write 'group by id' but I cannot count all rows.

Comment: @goGud I've expanded my answer. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I also solved it with count(distinct id)   :)